# Which control has the focus in my WPF window, how to find this in Live Visual Tree?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, user-interface, debugging

I'm starting to work with a GUI related application in WPF.

I'm using the Live Visual Tree in Visual Studio to investigate the controls on my WPF window.
I know how I can find a control in the Live Visual Tree and see its attributes, but I can't do the other way around:

I am selecting a control on my WPF window while debugging (it's a button), and I would like Visual Studio to open/select/show/jump to that particular control in the Live Visual Tree. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to enable the in-app toolbar for hot reload. Go to *Tools* > *Options...* in the menu. From there, select *Debugging* > *Hot-Reload* in the settings tree view. Tick the *Enable in-app toolbar* option.

[image: Hot-Reload options with the enable in-app toolbar checkbox.]

Then start debugging. At the top of your window, a black bar with buttons will appear. Select the *Track Focused Element* toggle button. After that, the *Live Visual Tree* will automatically jump to the currently focused element.

[image: In-App bar in debugging mode with option to track the focused element.]

Comment: Problem is the Visual Tree doesn't actually show the currently focused control always.  I see this when tabbing between text boxes in a datagrid.